# Voila not to Load Certain .ipynb Files

Tags: python, jupyter, voila

I am very new to Voila and Jupyter. I understand Jupyter notebook files (i.e. files with extension .ipynb) can be loaded in either Voila server or Jupyter server.

To elaborate, for instance, we have files below in the same folder: -

1. a.ipynb
2. b.ipynb

My question is that if it is possible for me only to load "a.ipynb" in Voila? The example is just for purpose of demonstration. We could have a large number of files / folders in the folder.

I have scanned through Voila website but doesn't look like there is any existing feature I can use to support this.

Thank you.

Comment: I had somehow not seen your post before. Though I'm not quite sure what you are asking here? Are you asking if there is a way to block users from accessing notebook `b.ipynb` from voila if it happens to be in the directory where a notebook you want access is, notebook `a.ipynb` in your example?

Comment: Thanks Wayne, yes, you were right. Sorry that the question wasn't clear. The goal is to only show in Voila browser session the notebooks that are compatible with Voila, when there are other ipynb notebooks (which should open in Jupyter Notebook) also existing in the same folder.

Comment: From [this](https://groups.google.com/g/jupyter/c/2E27IcsxADk/m/kCyAutTvCwAJ), I'd guess you are looking to use a handler to limit the endpoints. See [here](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extending/handlers.html) or  [here](https://jupyter-server.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developers/extensions.html). If you had metadata in the two different types of notebooks or a list of which notebook are in the one classification, I think you could draft code that parses that and makes index pages that feature the right set with launching URLs that would bifurcate the correct way.

Comment: Seems rather brittle though and what you ended up doing may just be easier if you can tolerate the separate directories. You may want to ask for advice at the [Jupyter Discourse Forum](http://discourse.jupyter.org/)?

Comment: Thank you Wayne. Sorry for not replying earlier...